# Where can I ask about configuring Discord Bots?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions about configuring different bots in my Discord server.

For example:

> - How do I sync [Nightbot](https://beta.nightbot.tv/) roles from Twitch?
> - Can I create a server whitelist for [Rhythm](https://rythmbot.co/)?
> - Why is [Mee6](https://mee6.xyz/) saying it deleted -1 messages?
> - How can I disable [Himebot's](https://himebot.xyz/) NSFW commands for all channels?

While [general Discord questions](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12450/358766) are considered on-topic for Super User, I don't think questions about server bots would fit there.

Is there a site where these questions would be on-topic?

Comment: SO probably?  They have a [discord tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord) there

Comment: @Dawny33 SO would only work if the questions were about programming.

Comment: Would Arqade be a good place for this? Discord is mainly used to organize players in multiplayer games such as Clash of Clans.

Comment: almost 5 years later, i have same question, and no decent answer... any news?